# SwiftUI Refresh list on state Change issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am facing an issue in refreshing a list based on a state change.
So I have a state variable which is using to show/hide a sheet , and while showing the sheet some data will be updated and the updated data needs to be shown on the list .This is my expectation , but the issue is that the list is not updating based on state change.As per my understanding , the entire View will be re-rendered when any state variable update happens, if so could anyone please check the below code and let me know why the list is not updating after the `self.showSheet.toggle()` inside the `ProcessDocument` closure:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var document: Doc
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: smallHeaderText("DETAILS")) {
                DocTypesPicker(fleetId: fleet?.fleetId ?? "", docTypeId: $document.doc_type)
            }
            
            Section(header: smallHeaderText("IMAGES")) {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailImagesPage(document: document) ) {
                    HStack {
                        let docImage = self. document.documentData?.first?.img ?? UIImage().jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: docImage!) ?? UIImage())
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(self.pageCountFor(document: self.document))
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.leading, 14)
                    }
                }.listRowBackground(Color.white)
            }
            
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Redo") {
                        self.showSheet.toggle()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ProcessDocument { docs in
                guard let docs = docs, let currentDoc = document.documentData else { return }

                document.removeFromDocumentData(currentDoc as NSSet)
                docs.forEach { doc in
                    let dateCreated = document.date_created
                    doc.doc_id = dateCreated
                    document.addToDocumentData(doc)
                }

                self.showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per my understanding , the entire View will be re-rendered when any state variable update happens

Not this is not that way, updated only parts of view's body (subviews) explicitly dependent on that state (ie. if state inside `Text` - only that one `Text` will be updated, even if you have 10 more other views in body).

In your case there is no other dependency on `showSheet` inside body except sheet itself, so nothing, including `List`, is updated.

If you want to refresh entire `List` explicitly on `showSheet` the possible solution could be as follows

```
List {
 // ... content here
}
.id(showSheet)    // << here !!
```